# How to replace textbox text within "" or {}

Tags: visual-studio-2012, textbox, replace

I am having trouble trying to replace text in a textbox with just a click of a button.

I would like to change lets say "354" with a number of my choice. I cannot use the normal

```
TextBox.Text = Replace(TextBox.Text, "354", "my text")
```

because the numbers 354 inside the quotes aren't always the same.

Comment: show some sample code you'll get an answer quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information you have given...

- txt_search is a textbox containing your desired string to be found and replaced
- txt_replace_with is a textbox you want to change the string to.

Then all you need is:

```
TextBox.Text = Replace(TextBox.Text,txt_search.text,txt_replace_with)
```

You can also use a inputbox() messagebox to get these two strings from the user if you wish.
... I dont have VS in front of me to check syntax but this is for the input boxes:

```
dim str_search = inputbox("What do you want to search for?")
dim str_replace = inputbox("... And replace that with what?")
TextBox.Text = Replace(TextBox.Text,str_search,str_replace)
```

Im sorry if any of the syntax is wrong on the inputbox.

Edit:

```
dim _loc  = instr(TextBox.Text,"<iframe width=")+15
dim _len = _loc - (instr(TextBox.Text,"height=")-2)
dim str_search = TextBox.Text.substring(_loc,_len)

_loc  = instr(TextBox.Text,"height=")+8
_len = _loc - (instr(TextBox.Text," src=")-1)

dim str_replace = TextBox.Text.substring(_loc,_len)

TextBox.Text = Replace(TextBox.Text,str_search,str_replace)
```

I may be slightly off with the offsets, but you can step threw and find that.

Comment: Sorry i didn't explain myself good. what i want to be able to do is change the video size of an embeded video: lets say i have this:  <iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XMF22_MEMJU?feature=player_detailpage" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>        I want to change the 640 and the 360 within the quotes with a different size with just the touch of a button.  Thanks for your fast reply

Comment: ok, then what you will have to do is use instr(TextBox.Text,"<iframe width=") to find the location of your iframe, then use ... textbox.text.substring(14,3) to find the first string, then the same for the second.